# Ansible when server group is not equal to

Tags: ansible

I am trying to restart `jboss` on server_group except cgfmgr, its failing. can some please help me with the syntax

TASK:

```
  - name: restarted jboss
    service: name=jboss state=restarted enabled=yes
    when: inventory_hostname in groups["{{ server_group }}:!cfgmgr-{{ server_group }}"]
```

Error-

> TASK: [restarted jboss]
>   *******************************************************  fatal: [ansible] => error while evaluating conditional: inventory_hostname in
>   groups["sit:!cfgmgr-sit"] FATAL: all hosts have already failed --
>   aborting

Hostfile

```
[sit:children]
jboss-sit
cfgmgr-sit
webserver-sit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use patterns when accessing `groups`' elements, only group names.

Try it with `group_names` magic variable:

```
  - name: restarted jboss
    service: name=jboss state=restarted enabled=yes
    when: server_group in group_names and ('cfgmgr-'+server_group) not in group_names
```

*This code is not tested.*